# Is there a way to bold a specific letter in text using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, moviepy

I have a question about ImageMagick.
I was creating a video with Moviepy (ImageMagick's Wrapper) and I wanted to bold one of the letters in the middle of the text.

However, such a feature did not seem to be available in Moviepy's TextClip, so I asked if this feature was available in ImageMagick.
Thanks.

Comment: In ImageMagick, the only ways to do that are to either use Pango: or to write some text in normal font, then your text for the one character in another bold font, then the rest of the text.  See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/  and  https://imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/

Comment: Thanks for the answer fmw42, by using pango I was able to create the video I wanted. Thank you very much.